# Como criar uma barra numérica superior no teclado do Android

Tags: java, android, edittext

Alguém sabe como criar no XML de um EditText aquela barra numérica em cima do teclado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa barra aparece quando você seta o inputType como textPassword, porém isso vai depender do teclado do Android.
Caso queira usar para um editText com texto visível, pode-se usar um textVisiblePassword.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

ou

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode configurar um [`inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Searchable_inputType) para o seu `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:inputType="textPassword|number" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

[Uma opção é usar um teclado customizado e adicionar ao seu projeto](https://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles/blob/master/app/src/main/java/name/boyle/chris/sgtpuzzles/SmallKeyboard.java). Pelo que eu sei você não vai conseguir isso com o teclado padrão do Android, pois não há opções no `android:inputType` que satisfaçam o que você precisa.

Comment: Obrigado, mas vou continuar aguardar por outras opiniões ou soluções, para ver se alguém sabe algo mais simples do que criar um teclado customizado...